# Count of sub-elements using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lua

I'm using NLua to embed Lua in my C# application.

I want to be able to read XML directly in Lua, but as I can't execute Linq in Lua and I haven't found any NLua-compatible library to read XML, I've decided to do it myself, using Linq.

I want to create a function which counts the number of elements in a XML file.

Here is the file:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
        </C>
        <C>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

I want to count how many "C" elements there is.

Here's my C# function:

```
public int CountElement(string elementName)
{
    var eltNames = from elt in handler.Elements(elementName)
                   select elt;

    return eltNames.Count();
}
```

If I call this with the parameter "C", it won't return my anything. Same for "B". But for "A", it will correctly returns me 1.

But I want it to be easy in Lua to access sub-elements, for instance:

`reader:CountElement("A.B.C")` to count the amount of "C" elements.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns only child elements of `handler`. You should get [descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get elements no matter where they are:

```
public int CountElement(string elementName)
{
    var eltNames = from elt in handler.Descendants(elementName)
                   select elt;

    return eltNames.Count();
}
```

Or same in shorter way

```
public int CountElement(string elementName)
{    
    return handler.Descendants(elementName).Count();
}
```

You also can use XPath if you want to count elements under some path like `A/B/C`:

```
handler.XPathSelectElements("A/B/C").Count()
```